# Does each instantiated object that inputs an ArrayList use the same reference to that ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

I have a flat file reader class that reads from dat files, creating person, customer, and product objects that are stored in their unique arraylist which I have to use for the getInvoice method. When inputing new attributes from the invoice dat file I create a new Product list for just the products that I have read from the invoice dat file. This seems to be working fine, however some product attributes are being changed on each invoice object.

When new invoice objects are instantiated with a product arraylist as a  field, does that create a reference to the product list that is added to in the code below or a copy of that list once it's made? If it is only a reference, why is it that when I read the product list in each invoice object, it has the correct amount of product objects per invoice (instead of all the products)? Also if i would clear the new product arraylist after creating an invoice object (which has product list as a field) then the product list in all of my invoices are empty. Why is this? If an arraylist will not work, how else can I do this? Thank you, I can add more code if needed.

```
public ArrayList<Invoice> getInvoices() {
    readPersons();
    readCustomers();
    readProducts();
    Scanner sc = null;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("data/Invoices.dat"));
        sc.nextLine(); 

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayList<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();
            String line = sc.nextLine(); 
            String data[] = line.split(";"); 
            String invoiceCode = data[0].trim();
            String customerCode = data[1].trim();
            Customer customer = null;
            for(Customer aCustomer: customerList) {
                if (customerCode.equals(aCustomer.getCustomerCode())) {
                    customer = aCustomer;
                    break;
                }
            }
            String personCode = data[2].trim();
            Person person = null;
            for(Person aPerson: personList) {
                if (personCode.equals(aPerson.getPersonCode())) {
                    person = aPerson;
                    break;
                }
            }
            String invoiceDate = data[3];
            String products[] = data[4].split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    String productData[] = products[i].split(":");
                    for(Product aProduct: productList) {
                        if (aProduct.getProductCode().equals(productData[0])) {
                            aProduct.setInvoiceDate(this.getDateTime(invoiceDate));
                            if (productData.length == 1) {
                                aProduct.setQuantity(1);
                                product.add(aProduct);
                            } else if (productData.length == 2) {
                                aProduct.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productData[1]));
                                product.add(aProduct);
                            } else if (productData.length == 3) {
                                aProduct.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productData[1]));
                                for(Product anotherProduct: product) {
                                    if (anotherProduct.getProductCode() == productData[2]) {
                                        aProduct.setParkingPassCount(anotherProduct.getQuantity());
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                product.add(aProduct);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            // Creates an Invoice object
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice(invoiceCode, invoiceDate, customer, person, product);

            // Adds the Invoice object into Invoice ArrayList
            invoiceList.add(invoice);   

        }
        sc.close();
        return invoiceList;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
public DateTime getDateTime(String Date){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(Date);
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: nope it doesn´t, it uses the references you are telling him to use. If you are refering to an already existing product and change some values for this product this will logically also reflect in changes to other collection where this exact instance is present, as it´s the same. (but it´s not really clear what you are trying to do and where you are stuck from your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but lets see; I guess your point is:

You have some **field** on your class (*invoiceList*); and your method there simply *appends* new Invoice objects to that list.

Assuming that the *invoiceList* object isn't cleared, or some other code calls

```
invoiceList = new ArrayList<>()
```

repeatedly, then your code is always using the **same** ArrayList object.

From a first glance, your overall design could be improved. You see, **adding** new objects to the same list means that you are relying on *side effects*. But on the other hand, your method is also *returning* the list you worked on. You should do one **or** the other; but not both.

So, option one - rely on using a field, like:

```
class InvoiceCollector {
   private final List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addNewInvoices() {
     ... reads data from file and adds new objects to invoices

   public List<Invoice> getCurrentInvoices() {
     return new ArrayList<>(invoices);
```

(returning a **copy** of that list prevents that code that receives that list references **manipulates it externally)

Option two: only return the last Invoices that were collected (and avoid having a **field** on that class altogether):

```
public List<Invoice> collectInvoices() {
  List<Invoice> invoices = ...
  ... all the code you have in your method
  return invoices;
}
```

Finally:

- read about the *Single Layer of Abstraction* principle. Your poor method is doing **way too much** in one spot. Better slice that up in many smaller methods
- Typically, a method called "getSomething()" wouldn't be do so much "computing". So, you might you should also look in how you *name* things to avoid surprising readers of your code!

Edit - to address your comment (and the "real" intention in your question): the first thing in your loop body is the creation of a new List called **product**. That thing is somehow populated; and in the end; that list object is given to the a new Invoice object. So: all the new invoice objects that are created should be using **different lists**.

And for the record: your **main** problem is that you have written so **hard to read** code. It starts with your variable names: product (being a LIST!), products (being an array), productList (which falls out of the sky), and so on). So, my personal recommendation: go in and **rework** your code to make it readable. Because then also **you** will understand what is doing.

Versus creating a **mess** of code; and then being in need for other people to explain to you what *your* code is doing.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. However my question pertains to the code where I make changes to the products in productlist and then add those specific products to a new product list. Each time that code loops (where I make a new productlist for updated products) is it creating a new arraylist? When I debug and look at the attributes for the products in each productlist, they are all the same.

Comment: @walrath21 if you get the `Product` from one `List`, make changes to it and store these references in another `List` for sure you are making changes to both products, as they are refering to the same instance of `Product` (techincally you only change one product). If you´d want to have a different product based on the values of another product include a copy constructor `Product(Product)` and create a new instance of `Product` base on another one.

Comment: @walrath21 I further enhanced my answer. Problem is: your code is so **confusing** that it is really hard to understand what you are doing, why your doing; and what is going wrong. Thus, as written: I think you should first focus on turning this mess into something readable. Honestly: you should consider throwing that thing away and starting from scratch. Or at least: turn to some peers and ask them to review your code.

Comment: @GhostCat I think part of the reason it is confusing is because I've only posted a snippet of code, however thank you for the suggestion on the single layer of abstraction. I think I need to go back and do that. What are all of your suggestions on making the code more readable? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Depending on the time you intend to invest; I recommend reading "Clean code" by Robert Martin. Ideally, you do that with your whole team. Then you start practicing.

Comment: @KevinEsche Perfect! I'm new to OOP and forgot that each time I change the quantity it's actually changing the quantity in the original product objects which is then referred to by each call after. I was focused on the ArrayList being the culprit and not the objects themselves. Thank you for the fix.